# How to transform using a math formula a signal in another one such that to keep the maximum of the first signal in the same position

Tags: graphing-functions, signal-processing

Let's say we have the following terms in a string (there is no formula for the next terms) 
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{ms} & \text{value}  \\\hline
1&1 \\\hline
2&2 \\\hline
3&3 \\\hline
4&4 \\\hline
5&5 \\\hline
6&6 \\\hline
7&9 \\\hline
8&10 \\\hline
9&12 \\\hline
10&13 \\\hline
11&7 \\\hline
12&6 \\\hline
13&5 \\\hline
14&11 \\\hline
15&13 \\\hline
16&15 \\\hline
17&17 \\\hline
18&20 \\\hline
19&20 \\\hline
20&20 \\\hline
21&18 \\\hline
22&17 \\\hline
23&16 \\\hline
24&15 \\\hline
25&13 \\\hline
26&11 \\\hline
27&10 \\\hline
28&9 \\\hline
29&8 \\\hline
30&7 \\\hline
31&5 \\\hline
32&3 \\\hline
33&1 \\\hline
34&0 \\\hline
\end{array}$$
For this table we have the following *input signal*:

[image]

From the table and from the picture it can be observed that the maximum it is around $18[\text{ms}]$ when the graph have the biggest value equals with $20$.

What I want to try is to create a "filter" such that the signal to be smoother and also the maximum of the "filter" to be almost in the same position with the *input signal*. The ideal case is the red curve from the following picture:
[image]

I am aware that the ideal case is very hard to be obtained, so I would like to obtain a formula which helps me to transform the input signal in another one smoother and with the maximum almost in the same position.

What I have tried was to sum all the time the first $8$ values and then to divide by 8, then to sum the elements starting from $2$[ms] to $9$[ms] and divided by 8, $\ldots$ and so on until starting from $27$[ms] to $34$[ms] and divided by 8, then starting from $28$[ms] to $34$[ms] and divided by 8, $\ldots$ $33$[ms] to $34$[ms] and divided by 8, $34$[ms] and divided by 8.

So, I obtain the following picture which is smoother but the maximum is not in almost the same position.

[image]

**Later edit**

I want to say that there is  a formula, but this formula is no so good because the maximum of the input is not in the same time with the maximum for the filter.

So,

$$\text{Filter}=\sum_{i=t-\text{buffer}}^{t}{\text{Input}_{t}},$$ where $\text{buffer}$ can be any value.

Comment: You can probably get your filter to work more like you want it to if you make sure it is symmetric around the point it filters. In other words take half of the values from the left and the other half from the right: $\text{Filter} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=t-\text{buffer}/2}^{\text{buffer}/2} \text{Input}_t$

Comment: Hello. I would like to ask you if is it correct $\text{buffer}/2$ in the superior part of the sum? thanks

Comment: Half of the values summed should be after the current sample and half before. Yes hmm, maybe it should be $t+\text{buffer}/2$ but I can't edit the comment any longer.

Comment: What shape curve would you like? Do you want it to be dome-shaped and have decreasing gradient as you have shown?  There are other ways of smoothing such as a moving average which will give you a smooth fit but your drawn curve implies you want a monotonic 2nd derivative.

Comment: P.S. your given method is similar to a moving average.

Comment: Also note, your given red line is always above the actual data. This means that your "red line" estimator will on average be a positively biased estimator of any given data point; which isn't typically what you want. You have drawn an estimator of the upper limit whereas you would typically be looking for an unbiased estimator which would by and large be above the actual data the same amout it's below it.  These questions need to be clarified really to give you a good answer.

Comment: @RobertFrost : I would not say it is sufficiently clear that he does not want something like an envelope detector instead of an unbiased estimator.

Comment: @mathreadler I agree it's unclear and as it stands there are many possible answers, having many diverse properties.

Comment: If you are to have the same maximum and to process this signal real time and also to have a smooth output, this is only possible if you output the 2nd signal with some delay after the first. Since otherwise the input could jump at any time and your output might have to jump with it. In other words your output signal at any time point will have to include in its calculation data points from later in the time series I  the first signal.

Comment: It is possible to make updates to least squares solutions on a per-sample basis. If it is a time signal, we don't know how we want the output to be represented. If it should be a signal or if we are more interested in some parametric model, which could be for example for prediction, extracting some property or detecting events. And maybe the most important factor of all (if it is a time series) : how many calculations do we have time to do between each new sample we get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you would like a method that you can apply to a wide class of input signals with the minimum of taylored adjustment of the parameters.

For that, I would proceed as follows:

1. do a mild pre-filtering of the signal, enough to smooth
   irregularities, without affecting too much the prominent maximum
   (maxima), e.g. a moving average with 2 or 3 steps;
2. amplify in a non linear way the resulting signal so as to enhance the maximum (maxima), e.g. raising to power (2 - 4), exponentiating, ...;
3. filter the resulting signal with a method of your choice as for the best smoothing, e.g. centered moving average, with a number of steps you retain sufficiently smooth
4. de-amplify

For instance, for the example you give a
m. avg. pre-f. of 2 st, a raise to power 4 and centered m. avg.filtering with 5 st, would give the following result

[image: Filter_4_5]

*Notes*

- Step 1- "pre-filtering" is optional, in the sense that you apply directly on the input signal a low-pass filtering to remove high frequency noise,
  if you expect the signal might come with some (mild= removing only highest non significant frequencies).
- I indicated moving average  because of its simple implementation and because it is quite effective. However other type of filtering can be applied.
- For what you need to achieve, *centered* moving average should be chosen in order to limit the shift in the resulting signal. That means that you take the average over a window with ca. $(n-1)/2$ points before and after the point in question, i.e. $$\overline x _k  = {1 \over n}\sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {(n - 1)/2} \right\rfloor \, \le \,j\, \le \,\left\lceil {(n - 1)/2} \right\rceil } {x_{k - j} } $$ . Then at the beginning and at the end, either you reduce the $n$, or pad the signal with $0$'s (or with a repetition of the signal if you want to make it periodic, etc.).
- From the structure of the formula above, you can recognize a *convolution* between the signal and a "box" (rectangular window) of width $n$ centered at the origin.
  That to indicate that you have further choices for the window to use beyond the rectangular one: each with its special features and target applications. A summary list of them is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).
- Literature to refer to is quite vast. You may start from [this wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)  at the point where it states : *"For a number of applications, it is advantageous to avoid the shifting induced by using only 'past' data. Hence a **central moving average** can be computed, using data equally spaced on either side of the point in the series where the mean is calculated"* and follow the links given there.
  In particular the link to the [Savitzky–Golay filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter), one the cited application for which is *"..Location of maxima and minima in experimental data curves. This was the application that first motivated Savitzky...."*.
- Final consideration is that, to orient yourself among the math/signal processing tools available, much (I would say all) depends on the physical considerations governing the input signal and intended application of the output.

Comment: This is very nice and it seems that you understood me perfectly. Please provide me some links with some examples from where I can understand things like "centered moving average", "mild pre-filtering ". Thanks!

Comment: @Iuli: I added some notes about the meaning of "centered" and "mild".

Comment: For what concerns the references you may use I tried and indicate a starting point, because literature on the subject is quite vast but dispersed: the indications I gave you come from a long experience.

Comment: Nice answer. +1 I helped with some typesetting if that's ok.

Comment: @mathreadler: thanks indeed, your cooperation is much appreciated and fully in the spirit of this site. And our answers complement themselves.

Comment: Is there any chance to do all this stuff without knowing what happens with the input signal in the future... What I want to say it is to do the calculation until a certain point - for example if I want to compute a certain formula for the an input point (let's say the value of the point at 4 [ms]) I would like to use only the value of the points from 1[ms], 2[ms], 3[ms] and eventually the value of the point from 4[ms], but I do not want to use the value of the point at 5[ms] or 6[ms]. Thanks for your nice work!

Comment: @Iuli If you are to process your signal "on-line" and not "off-line" then you can use clearly only *past* values. But in that case you shall forcedly accept a time lag for the position of the max: the larger the smoother you want to filter it. In fact you can view the matter as if all what said in my answer remain the same and then you shift back the resulting signal of half of the window aperture.

Comment: @Iuli: thanks for the bounty and pls. note a mistake in the comment above  which at the end should read " ... shift back the *input* signal  (= shift forward the output signal) by half ..."

Answer (score 4):

One approach you can try is to make a [weighted linear least squares (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) fit.

An unweighted [linear least squares (MathWorld)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) can be expressed $${\bf c_o} = \min_{\bf c}\|\bf \Phi c - d\|_2$$
Where the basis functions you fit to are stored as column vectors in $\bf \Phi$. Now what you can do is to add a diagonal weight matrix $\bf W$:

$${\bf c_o} = \min_{\bf c}\bf \|W(\Phi c -d)\|_2$$
We can make $\bf W$ have diagonal element corresponding to the maximum data point really big, say 100 or 1000 times as large as the rest of the diagonal elements. That will force the maximum point to stay in the same spot, but it won't ensure that no other point becomes bigger, which they can for example if you choose an unsuitable set of functions in $\bf \Phi$ to make the fit for. How easy it will be to choose a set of basis functions will depend a lot on what your data looks like. However for the data in your plot, probably a polynomial of order 2 or 4 will do fine.

Here is what it looks like for one configuration of parameters and polynomial degree $4$. It might not always be that polynomials are the best candidate functions to work with here.
[image]